# dd peculiarity with newlines

Tags: dd

According to the [sources](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html) I have read, dd block simply replaces newlines with spaces. Is this correct or are there other things at work.

The unix dd utility when used like so:

```
dd if=foo.log of=bar.log conv=block cbs=2
```

on a file like so:

```
12
34
56
78
9
```

I.e.

```
12\n34\n56\n78\n9\n
```

Should give:

```
12 34 56 78 9
```

Yet it gives

```
123456789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text there is be a little misleading.

Since you've asked for a output record size of two, that's exactly what you're getting. The newline will only be replaced by spaces if it doesn't already exceed the output record size.

I think it would be better to say something like:

> For each line in the input, output ‘cbs’ bytes, replacing the input newline with enough spaces as needed.

I originally thought that the docs may simply reflect the way things were done in the code, along the lines of:

- for every line:

  - replace newline at end with a space.
  - add spaces to pad to desired record length.
  - truncate to desired record length.

But, in fact, it doesn't. The latest `dd` source code has this (with my own comments added as well):

```
/* Copy NREAD bytes of BUF, doing conv=block
   (pad newline-terminated records to `conversion_blocksize',
   replacing the newline with trailing spaces).  */

static void copy_with_block (char const *buf, size_t nread) {
    size_t i;

    // For every single character in input buffer.

    for (i = nread; i; i--, buf++) { 
        // If we find a newline.

        if (*buf == newline_character) {
            // If output record no filled up, pad with spaces.

            if (col < conversion_blocksize) {
                size_t j;
                for (j = col; j < conversion_blocksize; j++)
                    output_char (space_character);
            }

            // Regardless, start new output record.

            col = 0;
        } else {
            // No newline.
            // If we hit output limit, increment truncated-lines count.
            // Otherwise only output character if under limit.

            if (col == conversion_blocksize)
                r_truncate++;
            else
                if (col < conversion_blocksize)
                    output_char (*buf);

            // Regardless, increment characters-on-this-line count.

            col++;
        }
    }
}
```

In this, you're clearly processing a character at a time using a global `col` to store your output column. It clearly states that as soon as you find the newline in the input stream, it is replaced with spaces up to the conversion block size.

And if you don't find the newline before you hit the conversion block size, al the other characters are simply discarded, up to and including the next newline.

Comment: I didn't even bother to look at the dd code for fear it would be indecipherable and obfuscated. Thanks this helps immensely!

Comment: Don't be lulled into a false sense of security, @Dominic, it's both indecipherable _and_ obfuscated. It's just that my mind is so bent from cryptic crosswords and looking at questionable code for thirty-odd years that code like that sort of just 'osmotes' into my consciousness :-)

Comment: +1; would be great to give back the comments to maintainer :)

Comment: I hereby release my comments into the public domain. Feel free to use them in any way you see fit, commercial or otherwise. Note that this doesn't apply to the _code_ since that is from the original work. Only the comments are public domain. If your particular legal jurisdiction doesn't recognise the public domain, I hereby grant you a multiverse-wide, non-revocable-under-any-circumstances, non-exclusive, perpetual, any-use licence to use these comments, provided you indemnify me against any action, legal or otherwise, that such use may cause :-)